# Dynamically switching control user depending on if "user is logged in or not"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm kind of confused how am I suppose to do that.
Been reading things for couple hours now.
Some people add controls to panels some do add it to placeholders,
now I kind of don't know how to do it..

I need for navigator bar, I have one navigtor bar in control user that shows avatar, user nickname etc., and another user control is for user that is not logged in to the site. I need a way to switch between those 2 controls depending on if session != null

Anyone has any idea how to do that?

Comment: can't you just overlap the controls? If user logged in, hide the controls you dont need anymore and show avatar

Comment: @Nitro.de You are probably right, but I don't even know how to use them properly as I stated in post above x_ x

Comment: Well if you have no idea how to use the Controls in ASP.Net you should [start reading](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/ui_and_navigation) a bit

Comment: @Nitro.de I know how controls works, I just don't know how to include them in html file with code behind. Some people inserts them into panels and some into place holders.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, for anyone that would be looking for it anytime soon.

```
            <asp:Panel ID="nave" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

And cs

```
            UserControl uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/controls/navlog.ascx");
            nave.Controls.Add(uc);
```